# Customise result key in doctrine-mongo odm

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

How can we change result key name in doctrine-mongo odm. I just want change "**id:Application\Document\Page:private**" to "**id**"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Application\Document\Page Object
        (
            [id:Application\Document\Page:private] => 55fa06f29d6d75f0020041a7
            [name:Application\Document\Page:private] => test page
        )

    [1] => Application\Document\Page Object
        (
            [id:Application\Document\Page:private] => 55fa0bf59d6d755d030041a7
            [name:Application\Document\Page:private] => Focus
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can add  `->hydrate(false)` with `createQueryBuilder`

```
$user = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Application\Document\User')
        ->field('username')->equals($username)
        ->field('status')->equals('active');
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->select(array('username', 'status','guid','device_token'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute()
        ->toArray();
```